# Playbook host_group files

Tags: ansible

Задача:

При помощи playbook разложить sudoers файлы на сервера, но у каждого сервера, вернее у каждой группы серверов, свой уникальный файл настроек. В директории roles/files лежат файлы именованные по host_group.

Возможно ли это или придётся для каждого хоста держать отдельный файл sudoers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Ansible нет такого понятия, как host_group.

Если говорить о группах, то на их названия тоже не стоит завязываться, т.к. один хост может быть в разных группах и для выбора нужного файла по имени группы (если их несколько) нужно будет придумывать какую-то логику.

Правильный путь – добавить переменную для группы (sudoers_file) и использовать её при копировании файла.

inventory:

```
[gr1]
host1
host2
[gr1:vars]
sudoers_file=sudoers_gr1
[grp2]
hostA
hostB
[grp2:vars]
sudoers_file=sudoers_grp2
```

task:

```
- copy:
    src: "{{ sudoers_file }}"
    dest: /etc/sudoers
    validate: visudo -cf %s
```